# Getting undefined on a single value while others work when fetching api

Tags: javascript, fetch

I'm fetching from an API and everything seems to work, items are fetched, 
yet I'm getting an undefined in the beginning of the page

as you can see here: https://codepen.io/makeyka/pen/OJRoPJK

```js
    fetch('https://gorest.co.in/public-api/users')
              .then(res => res.json())
              .then((json) => {
                let html
                console.log(json.data)
                json.data.forEach((user) => {
                    for (let x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
                        let data = json.data[x]
                        html += 
                            `
                                <div style="display: inline-block;">
                                    <div class="center">
                                        <h2>ID</h2>
                                        <span>${data.id}</span>

                                        <h2>Name</h2>
                                        <span>${data.name}</span>

                                        <h2>Status</h2>
                                        <span style="color:${data.status == 'Active' ? "green" : "red"};">
                                            ${data.status}
                                        </span>

                                        <h2>Email</h2>
                                        <span>
                                            <a href="mailto:${data.email}" target="_blank">
                                                ${data.email}
                                            </a>
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            `
                    }
                })
                document.querySelector('#r00t').innerHTML = html
            })
```

Comment: `let html` and then later `html += ...` causes your issue, there's no value to add the new string to.

Comment: @Teemu - And they were easier to find than I thought they'd be. :-) Makeyka, see the linked question's answers. `html` starts out with the value `undefined` because you haven't assigned it any initial value here: `let html;` Later, you do this: `html += /*...*/`.
`+=` *adds to* the current value. So the first time you're effectively doing: `html = undefined + /*...*/` ...so you get `undefined` at the beginning. Initialize `html` with `""` if you want to avoid that.

Comment: @Makeyka - If you like, you can delete the question, since there are lots of versions of it on the site. Happy coding!